# Grouping user into Role to access FDW table

Tags: postgresql, users, role, postgresql-12, postgresql-fdw

Recently I setup Forward Data Wrapper. Here is what I do:

```
CREATE SERVER foreign_server FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS (host '192.168.125.1', port '5432', dbname 'template1 ');  
IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA public LIMIT TO (tbl_test) FROM SERVER foreign_server INTO public;
```

Create a user on the destination / foreign server : `CREATE USER fdwuser WITH PASSWORD 'secret'`
And then do the necessary settings like `GRANT`. The FDW works.

But then I want to do more. What if I assemble all the users that want to access FDW into a `GROUP`. Then I do the following:

- `Create group role` : demorole1
- `create user` : fdwuser3
- `grant demorole1 to fdwuser3`
- create user mapping for group role "demorole1" :

  CREATE USER MAPPING FOR demorole1 SERVER foreign_server OPTIONS (user 'fdwuser', password 'secret');
- `select * from tbl_test;` -- **failed**.
- grant demorole1 access to tbl_test, schema and foreign server : `GRANT ALL ON TABLE tbl_test TO demorole1;` `GRANT USAGE ON FOREIGN SERVER foreign_server TO demorole1;` `GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO fdwuser3;`
- Test : `select * from tbl_test;`  --**failed**. user mapping not found for user fdwuser3
- `CREATE USER MAPPING FOR demorole1 SERVER foreign_server OPTIONS (user 'fdwuser', password 'secret');`
- Test again : `select * from tbl_test;`  -- still **failed**. user mapping not found for "fdwuser3"
- Do user mapping : `CREATE USER MAPPING FOR fdwuser3 SERVER foreign_server OPTIONS (user 'fdwuser', password 'secret');`
- `select * from tbl_test;` --***WORKS***

Question : How can I create a group role so that the users on the local server can be set as it's member so I don't have to do Granting and Creating user mapping every time there is user wants to access FDW table ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not supported. You can either create a user mapping for the user itself or for `PUBLIC`, that is, for everybody. These are your choices. A user mapping created for a role will not be used for a member of that role. That is working as designed.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change of role of group before;
set rote demorole1;
select * from tbl_test;